# Request json Data

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I getting the stuck while post the Request json data with bearer token in c#.

EX - Jsondata

```
"{"data":{"POLICY_NO":"29991231030","POLICY_TYPE":"1","HEGICCardNo_Var":"HC1801724-01A"}}"
```

response:

```
{StatusCode: 403, 
 ReasonPhrase: 'Forbidden', 
 Version: 1.1, 
 Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, 
 Headers:
 {
  Pragma: no-cache
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Date: Sat, 02 Mar 2019 06:21:40 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Length: 28
  Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
  Expires: -1
}}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] the question to include more information about what you are trying to do when you get this error, and what code you are using in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: While I post to above JSON request in Web API URL like this code.                                                                 Res = client.postAsasync(URL, JSON request). result;.                                                                       then Res getting 403 forbidden.

Answer (score 1):

While posting the Json data in web service Respective url with Bearer Token.

Then First Add the AuthenticationHeaderValue as Below C# Code :

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization/Bearer", TokenValue);

HttpResponseMessage messge = client.PostAsync(Url,ContentObj).Result;